# Fastlane distribution failed with error "App Distribution could not find your app"

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, fastlane

I am developing react-native project for Android and iOS.

I use Fastlane to distribute my Android app to Firebase App Distribution. I have followed [firebase instruction](https://rnfirebase.io/) and [fastlane instruction](https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/android/beta-deployment/) to set up those tools.

In fastlane part, here is my `Fastfile` :

```
desc "Submit a new Beta Build to firebase app distribute"
  lane :beta do
    gradle(task: "clean assembleRelease")

    firebase_app_distribution(
      app: "1:4823523451:android:fb106cd9iu76gr3ededc0",
      firebase_cli_token: "1//0cDO6RQESnRMvCgYIACAAgAwSNwF-L9IrPk97hOEsuXxXNHXUfpKQRsiAsqu_mmGhGmOPoIfdfThgjHoKlJS4X4auLr_d2QoLSXg",
      groups: "qa-team, trusted-testers",
      release_notes: "my 1st release",
      testers: "n1cer4@gmail.com",
      debug: true)
  end
```

The `firebase_cli_token` above is the refresh token I take by run command `bundle exec fastlane run firebase_app_distribution_login`

The app id is correct as well.

When I run `fastlane beta`, I end up with the following error which says `App Distribution could not find your app. Make sure to onboard your app by pressing the "Get started" button on the App Distribution page in the Firebase console`
(I hide some sensitive information in the screenshot ):

[image]

I don't see the error message mentioned "Get started" button. And when I go to my firebase console, the apk file is uploaded there:

[image]

So, why I got that error when run `fastlane beta` ?

(BTW, in above screenshot, you can see it indicates one tester is invited, actually I added that tester manually on the firebase console, as you can see my `Fastfile` has `testers` defined but they are not added as testers by fastlane, I guess it is because of the error I am encountering.)

Answer (score 13):

When you click on the app distribution tab, there is a drop down menu next to the header for android and iOS projects. You have to click the "get started" for both.

Comment: I was getting a 404 response after configuring everything, and this solved my issue

Comment: That's the issue for me too. Fastlane just simply gave me a 404 error but if you test with Firebase CLI, it will give you the error that actually help! `Error: App Distribution could not find your app {YOUR_APP_ID} Make sure to onboard your app by pressing the "Get started" button on the App Distribution page in the Firebase console: https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/appdistribution`

Answer (score 5):

If you have multiple flavors/apps in your project, make sure to press the "get started" button for each of them (check in the dropdown near the "App Distribution" title)

If you still encounter the issue, check the API responses given with debug=true, since the "could not find your app" message is very misleading and happens with every 404 response. In my case, I was putting the wrong "groups" parameter.

Comment: I only have one Android app added to my firebase project. I don't have multiple.

Comment: How to check API response ? Could you please be more specific?

Comment: Having a wrong "groups" value was causing this error for me.

Comment: @Leem.fin if you put debug: true inside the firebase_app_distribution lane you will see the response of the API calls

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had authenticated Fastlane using Firebase service account credentials. I encountered the same error

> App Distribution could not find your app. Make sure to onboard your
> app by pressing the "Get started" button on the App Distribution page
> in the Firebase console

I noticed there was an additional service account I had configured wrongly. After deleting the account, I was able to distribute.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. I solved it updating the plugins:

```
bundle exec fastlane update_plugins
```

Also, the fastlane help recommended the last version. I installed it executing:

```
sudo gem install fastlane
```